# Codeigniter removes inline style from html input

Tags: php, codeigniter, xss, user-input, validation

Taking a look at the following code:

```
$this->input->post('title', FALSE);
```

I have manually disabled XSS filtering.

Now lets see some examples:

```
<p BAD_ATTR_KEY="BAD_ATTR_VAL">Salam</span>
```

RETURNS:

```
<p BAD_ATTR_KEY="BAD_ATTR_VAL">Salam</span>
```

---

```
<p style="color: red;">Salam</span>
```

RETURNS:

```
<p  red;">Salam</span>
```

Any ideas how to disable this behavior so that the site admins will be able to easily assign different inline styles to any element on the page?

---

**UPDATE:**

I have enabled global XSS filtering in `application/config/config.php` because I need it all the time.

I don't need XSS filtering only when trusted admins are posting their content from back end. For that purpose I have manually disabled XSS filtering as mentioned in my code above. And I think that the manual config should override default config estated at `config.php`, so there should be no problem with that.

Comment: Looks to me like there's still XSS filtering going on. Did you disable in config.php?

Comment: @Asad As I know, enabling and disabling it in config.php, only changes the default behaviour. But now, I have manually disabled it cause I need it all time except for now.

Comment: @Asad you were right. Please post your comment as an answer so that I be able to accept it. But why should not that be overrided manually? So what does the second parameter do in `$this->input->post()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found what my problem was according to [Asad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1726343/asad)'s comment.

Even now that I had manually disabled XSS filtering using:

```
$body = $this->input('body', FALSE);
```

, that was still being removed because I had enabled XSS filtering in `application/config/config.php`.

I don't really know why it couldn't be overrided using the second parameter anyway.

Comment: I had it on TRUE too, now I turned it to FALSE, and still I get the style attribute stripped off... :S any clues?

Comment: Are you sure that you are setting the second parameter to `FALSE`?

Comment: I found the problem... I was using form validation and that particular field was getting prepped with the xss_clean function (more on prepping data with form validation here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#preppingdata)

Answer (score 1):

I spent around 5hrs at this problem and find the simple solution.
First you need to find the security class, which is located in your project/application/core and if any codeigniter cms used then in project/system/codeigniter/core/security

There it will be a function with the name '_remove_evil_attributes'(protected method)
In this function there will be a line 
$evil_attributes = array('on\w*', 'style', 'xmlns', 'formaction');
if you want to allow style attribute in your input elements or textareas then you need to remove the 'style' from here to allow style attributes to work properly, otherwise they will automatically be replaced with this line of code written in this function below

$str = preg_replace('/<(/?[^><]+?)([^A-Za-z<>-])(.*?)('.implode('|', $attribs).')(.*?)([\s><])([><]*)/i', '

So beware of this thing, don't waste your precious time as i did. 
Haisum 
Thanks

Comment: nice, thank you it works too and it explains much but how to do this without modifying the core files? can't we override the function or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Look not the solution but the **workaround**.

For me, I **cannot disable** global XSS filtering for security reasons.

So, I did this.

```
<h1 stile="color:red;">Red</h1>
```

Note that the `style` is written as `stile`.

Which is accepted even with `$this->input->post('body', TRUE);`

Now, I have used `str_replace("stile", "style", $body);` in frontend.

Maybe not the best solution but a working workaround.